# Using Netty within Spring Boot, service method with @Transactional annotation did not respond

Tags: java, spring, transactions, netty

I am working on a project using Spring Boot, Netty , Mybatis, MySQL.

```
package com.lanwon.ifpserver;

import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan({"com.lanwon.ifpserver.dao"})
public class App {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
            app.setWebEnvironment(false);
            app.run(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Then the Netty Server implements ApplicationContextAware and takes care of ApplicationContext.

```
package com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.config.ServerConfig;

@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServerConfig.class)
public class IfpServer implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IfpServer.class);

    private EventLoopGroup masters = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    private EventLoopGroup workers = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    @Resource
    private ServerConfig serverConfig;

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @PostConstruct
    public void start(){
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap().group(masters, workers);
        bootstrap = bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        bootstrap = bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, serverConfig.getBacklog());
        bootstrap = bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, serverConfig.isNodelay());
        bootstrap = bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, serverConfig.isKeepAlive());           
        bootstrap.childHandler(new IfpChannelInitializer());

        try{
            ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind(Integer.valueOf(serverConfig.getPort())).sync();
            log.info("Netty Server started......");
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            stop();
        }

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() {

        workers.shutdownGracefully();
        masters.shutdownGracefully();

    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx)
            throws BeansException {
        IfpServer.ctx = ctx;
        String[] all = ctx.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(Component.class);
        for(String n: all)
            log.info(n);
        log.info(getBean("ifpControlProcessor").getClass().getName());
    }

    public static Object getBean(String id){
        return ctx.getBean(id);
    }

}
```

Here comes the ChannelInitializer which is not created by Spring Boot.

```
package com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty;

import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.decoder.IfpMessageDecoder;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.handlers.IfpMessageHandler;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;

public class IfpChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {

        ChannelPipeline pipe = channel.pipeline();
        pipe.addLast(new IfpMessageDecoder());
        pipe.addLast(new IfpMessageHandler());

    }

}
```

And the Decoder and Handler which are not created by Spring Boot either.
Decoder:

```
package com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.decoder;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.lanwon.commons.lang.BitOpUtils;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.IfpServer;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.config.MessageConfig;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.messages.BaseMessage;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.messages.IfpMessage;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.messages.ParamMessage;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder;

public class IfpMessageDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder{

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IfpMessageDecoder.class);

    private MessageConfig messageConfig;

    public IfpMessageDecoder(){
        messageConfig = (MessageConfig) IfpServer.getBean("messageConfig");
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in,
            List<Object> out) throws Exception {

        if(in.readableBytes() < messageConfig.getHeaderLength()){
            return;
        }

        in.markReaderIndex();

        byte[] headerBytes = new byte[9];
        in.readBytes(headerBytes);
        BaseMessage header = validateHeader(headerBytes);
        if(header == null){
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }

        IfpMessage message = new IfpMessage();
        log.info("Header received: {}", header);
        if(header.getType() == 0xff){
            message.setHeader(header);
            out.add(message);
            log.info("Control Message received. Turn to Handler directly");
            return;
        }
        if(in.readableBytes() < messageConfig.getParamControlLength()){
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        byte[] paramsArray = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
        in.readBytes(paramsArray);
        ParamMessage params = validateParam(paramsArray);
        if(params==null){
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }
        log.info("Parameters received: {}", params);
        message.setHeader(header);
        message.setParams(params);
        out.add(message);

    }

    private ParamMessage validateParam(byte[] params) {
        ParamMessage pm = new ParamMessage();
        pm.setCommand(BitOpUtils.bytesToInt(params));
        pm.setAccessory(params[4]);
        pm.setParameterSize(BitOpUtils.bytesToInt(params, 5));
        byte[] p = Arrays.copyOfRange(params, 9, params.length);
        try {
            pm.setParameterMessage(p);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Parameter Encoding: {}", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return pm;
    }

    private BaseMessage validateHeader(byte[] headerBytes) {

        BaseMessage bm = new BaseMessage();
        int flagLength = messageConfig.getFlagLength();
        byte[] flag = Arrays.copyOf(headerBytes, flagLength);
        try {
            bm.setFlag(flag);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Header Encoding: {}", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        bm.setType(headerBytes[flagLength]);
        bm.setMsgCode(headerBytes[flagLength+1]);
        bm.setMsgCode1(headerBytes[flagLength+2]);
        bm.setVersion(headerBytes[flagLength+3]);
        if(!"FAP".equals(bm.getFlag())){
            log.info("Header Protocol.");
            return null;
        }
        if(bm.getVersion()!=messageConfig.getCurrentVersion()){
            log.info("Header Version");
            return null;
        }
        return bm;

    }

}
```

Handler:

```
package com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.handlers;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.IfpServer;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.messages.IfpMessage;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.processors.BaseProcessor;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.processors.IfpControlProcessor;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;

public class IfpMessageHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IfpMessageHandler.class);

    private IfpControlProcessor ifpControlProcessor;

    public IfpMessageHandler(){
        ifpControlProcessor = (IfpControlProcessor) IfpServer.getBean("ifpControlProcessor");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        log.info("Disconnected: {}", ctx.channel().remoteAddress());
        super.channelInactive(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
            throws Exception {
        BaseProcessor processor = null;
        if(msg instanceof IfpMessage){
            IfpMessage message = (IfpMessage) msg;
            log.info("Processing header：{}", message.getHeader());
            if(message.getParams()==null){
                processor = ifpControlProcessor;
            }
            IfpMessage resp = processor.process(null);
            ctx.writeAndFlush(buffer(resp.serialize()));
        }
    }

    private ByteBuf buffer(byte[] msg){
        return Unpooled.copiedBuffer(msg);
    }

}
```

Then the Service Processor.

```
package com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.processors;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.messages.BaseMessage;
import com.lanwon.ifpserver.netty.messages.IfpMessage;

@Service
@Transactional
public class IfpControlProcessor extends BaseProcessor {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IfpControlProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public IfpMessage process(String paramJson) {
        IfpMessage resp = new IfpMessage();
        resp.setHeader(new BaseMessage());
        resp.setParams(null);
        BaseMessage header = resp.getHeader();
        header.setFlag("FAP");
        header.setType(0xff);
        header.setMsgCode(2);
        header.setMsgCode1(0);
        header.setVersion(5);
        return resp;
    }

}
```

Here the problem is, when I added @Transactional annotation to Service Class or Service Method, the process method will not return. And no any console output gave out. It just did not respond, also the Netty Channel did not respond either. When I remove the @Transactional annotation, It worked pretty well.

So why would this happen? Cause later Service will need the transaction feature. I shall need the @Transactional annotation as well.

Thanks for your concern.